# How do i change this react router v5 code that uses props to v6

Tags: reactjs

Since props don't work with v6 what should i do to make this code work with v6. How do i pass the right information so that the information is displayed as intended.

Snippet from restaurant.js

```
const Restaurant = props => {
  const initialRestaurantState = {
    id: null,
    name: "",
    address: {},
    cuisine: "",
    reviews: []
  };
  const [restaurant, setRestaurant] = useState(initialRestaurantState);

  const getRestaurant = id => {
    RestaurantDataService.get(id)
      .then(response => {
        setRestaurant(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRestaurant(props.match.params.id);
  }, [props.match.params.id]);
```

Snippet from App.js

```
 <Route path="/restaurants/:id"render={(props) => (
 <Restaurant {...props} user={user} />)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useParams`

```
...
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
...

...
const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    getRestaurant(params.id);
}, [params.id]);
...
```

Here is the reference https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams

Comment: Just a dumb question do i still pass the props?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some part of your code:
first, use `useParams` instead of `props.match.params.id`:

```
const params = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    getRestaurant(params.id);
}, [params.id]);
```

second, there isn't any `render` prop on `Route` component and you should use `element` instead of `render`:

```
 <Route path="/restaurants/:id" element={(props) => (
 <Restaurant {...props} user={user} />)}/>
```

Comment: do i still pass the props???

Comment: @RobertJoasilus What do you mean?

Comment: im sorry i mean how do i access user in the other function. Is it just props.user

Comment: @RobertJoasilus yes